# A nonsplit extension of a nonabelian finite simple group by a cyclic group of odd prime order

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-cohomology, simple-groups, group-extensions

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Does a nonabelian finite simple group $S$ exist such that $H^2(S, \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is not trivial?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example $S={\rm PSL}(p,q)$ where $p|q-1$. Then ${\rm SL}(p,q)$ is a non-split extension of $C_p$ by $S$.